Identify this (recent?) U.S. action movie
I think I saw a movie where a guy was selling rifles that locked up when they were pointed at one another, to prevent friendly fire. I remember the seller demonstrating their use by firing a bunch of bullets and sweeping through some guys holding guns who didn't get hit. This scene had some wealthy warlords observing the demonstration, which was in a poorly lit brick tunnel/basement. I'm pretty sure the main protagonists were not in the scene, but the main antagonists probably were.

I think it was a movie. It could have been an episode of a TV show, but I can't think of a show I watch that would have black market weapons dealers.
It was probably a U.S. action movie, released in 2007-2013


Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

The date and the description don't really match, but the scene you mention reminds me a lot of a scene in the 
The Fifth Element where Zorg presents the new gun that his company developed.
He demonstrates the replay function of the gun, a system where the bullets automatically reach the last target. He does so pretty much as you said: by shooting in the direction of his allies, but all the bullets turn back to go to the practice dummy. (The scene on youtube)

That was my thought too. It should be noted that the 5th element was a French film, though.

@DA Yes, the movie itself is French, but originally in English with the main roles given to Bruce Willis, Gary Oldman and Milla Jovovich. Forgivable assumption of the asker if this movie is the answer :)

That scene had some similarities, but I've never seen the 5th Element. The scene I'm thinking of had no futuristic qualities to it that I recall. Even the unique weapons were something that the U.S. military has considered implementing; I found this during my futile search: http://www.military.com/NewsContent/0,13319,135837,00.html
